# Error passing ViewModel to View using EF Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a ViewModel passing to Views and am getting a strange error:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   ViewDataDictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BizDevHub.Models.Intermediary]',
>   but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BizDevHub.ViewModels.IntermediaryViewModel]'.

I cannot understand why as it seems that I am passing the ViewModel to the View and not the Model.

**My Models**

```
public class Intermediary
{
    public int IntermediaryID
    public string RegisteredName { get; set; }
    public string TradingName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
}

public class Branch
{
    public int BranchID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Creation Date")]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [DisplayName("Created By")]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

**My ViewModel**

```
public class IntermediaryViewModel
{
    public int IntermediaryID { get; set; }
    [Required,StringLength(150),DisplayName("Registered Name")]
    public string RegisteredName { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(150), DisplayName("Registered Name")]
    public string TradingName { get; set; }
    public int Registration { get; set; }
    public int VATNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FSPNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Creation Date")]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [DisplayName("Created By")]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public int BranchID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
}
```

**My Views**

```
@model IEnumerable<BizDevHub.ViewModels.IntermediaryViewModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RegisteredName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TradingName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Registration)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VATNumber)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FSPNumber)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreationDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BranchID)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RegisteredName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TradingName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Registration)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VATNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FSPNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreationDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedBy)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BranchID)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.IntermediaryID">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.IntermediaryID">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.IntermediaryID">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>


@model BizDevHub.ViewModels.IntermediaryViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<h4>Intermediary</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RegisteredName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="RegisteredName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="RegisteredName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TradingName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="TradingName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TradingName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Registration" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Registration" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Registration" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="VATNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="VATNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="VATNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FSPNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FSPNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FSPNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CreatedBy" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CreatedBy" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CreatedBy" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BranchID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="BranchID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BranchID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="DepartmentID">Branch</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentID", null, new {@class="form-group"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BranchID)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**My Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using BizDevHub.Data;
using BizDevHub.Models;
using BizDevHub.ViewModels;

namespace BizDevHub.Controllers
{
    public class IntermediariesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly BizDevHubContext _context;

        public IntermediariesController(BizDevHubContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Intermediaries
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Intermediaries.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Intermediaries/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var intermediary = await _context.Intermediaries
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IntermediaryID == id);
            if (intermediary == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(intermediary);
        }

        // GET: Intermediaries/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            PopulateBranchDropDownList();
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Intermediaries/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("IntermediaryID,RegisteredName,TradingName,Registration,VATNumber,FSPNumber,CreationDate,CreatedBy,BranchID")] IntermediaryViewModel intermediary)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(intermediary);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            PopulateBranchDropDownList(intermediary.BranchID);
            return View(intermediary);
        }

        // GET: Intermediaries/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var intermediary = await _context.Intermediaries.FindAsync(id);
            if (intermediary == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(intermediary);
        }

        // POST: Intermediaries/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("IntermediaryID,RegisteredName,TradingName,Registration,VATNumber,FSPNumber,CreationDate,CreatedBy,BranchID")] IntermediaryViewModel intermediary)
        {
            if (id != intermediary.IntermediaryID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(intermediary);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!IntermediaryExists(intermediary.IntermediaryID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            PopulateBranchDropDownList(intermediary.BranchID);
            return View(intermediary);
        }

        // GET: Intermediaries/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var intermediary = await _context.Intermediaries
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IntermediaryID == id);
            if (intermediary == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(intermediary);
        }

        // POST: Intermediaries/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var intermediary = await _context.Intermediaries.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Intermediaries.Remove(intermediary);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool IntermediaryExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Intermediaries.Any(e => e.IntermediaryID == id);
        }

        private void PopulateBranchDropDownList(object selectedBranch = null)
        {
            var branchesQuery = from d in _context.Branch
                                orderby d.Name
                                select d;
            ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(branchesQuery, "DepartmentID", "Name", selectedBranch);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You have not posted your controller code, that's where the issue is. Make sure you pass `IEnumerable<BizDevHub.ViewModels.IntermediaryViewModel>` to the view. Right now you're passing `List<Intermediary>`.

Comment: My aplogies. I have updated the question.

Comment: My comment above is still valid. You need to create a `IntermediaryViewModel` and assign values to it from the `Intermediary`. Then pass the `IntermediaryViewModel` to your view.

Comment: Could you assist me to do the mapping to the view?

Comment: It's easy. Once you get the intermediary like this: `var intermediary = await _context.Intermediaries.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IntermediaryID == id);` then create a view model `var vm = new IntermediaryViewModel; vm.IntermediaryID = intermediary.IntermediaryID; // Do the other properties too return View(vm)`. If your view expects a list or ienumerable then do add the viewmodel, all of them, to a list `var vms = new List<IntermediaryViewModel>(); vms.Add(vm);`

Comment: You're not thinking straight. I said from the beginning, you need to pass the correct thing to the `View` method in the controller. The correct thing is whatever you expect in your `.cshtml` view. In the code above, you're passing `await PaginatedList<Intermediary>.CreateAsync(intermediaries.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize)`. You cannot do that. You need to call that query outside the `View` method, convert the results to the type you expect in your `.cshtml` and then pass the converted type to `View`. You need to pay attention to your code and what you're doing.

Comment: I have updated the question with my attempt to implement what you said.  2 issues, I do not contect my context with the ViewModel and I am not sure how to pass the ViewModel to the final View();  
Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

For:

```
return View(await _context.Intermediaries.ToListAsync());
```

and

```
return View(intermediary);
```

You seem to be passing the View objects of type Intermediary, not IntermediaryViewModel, unless your context is somehow converting them in other code.  I don't see any code that's mapping the entity (Intermediary) to the ViewModel (IntermediaryViewModel).  Perhaps use AutoMapper or something similar to convert your EF entities into the ViewModel.

Comment: Would you be able to help me with the mapping? I prefer not using AutoMapper.

Answer (score 1):

I see couple of issues with your code.

1. Your views are taking ViewModel/s as input. But you are returning Model object in Index action. **So, in order to fix the error that is shown in the title of this POST**, please update your index action to convert colleciton of model objects to collection of viewmodel objects.

> ```
> public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
> {
>     var intermediaryViewModels = ModelsToViewModelsConversion(_context.Intermediaries.ToListAsync());
>     return View(intermediaryViewModels);
> }
>
> private async List<IntermediaryViewModel>() ModelsToViewModelsConversion(IEnumerable<Intermediary> models)
> {
>     // conversion code goes here.
>     // return collection of IntermediaryViewModel;
> }
> ```

2. Create GET action (// GET: Intermediaries/Create) is not returning any object, but view is expecting instance of  IntermediaryViewModel. So, you need to modify your Create GET Action as below:

> ```
> // GET: Intermediaries/Create
> public IActionResult Create()
> {
>   // PopulateBranchDropDownList();
>   var branchesQuery = from d in _context.Branch
>       orderby d.Name
>       select d;
>   return View(new IntermediaryViewModel{Branches = branchesQuery.AsEnumerable() });
> }
> ```

And update your Create.cshtml as below to display the branches:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="DepartmentID">Branch</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentID", new SelectList(Model.Branches, "DepartmentID", "Name"), new { @class = "form-group" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BranchID)
    </div>
</div>
```

What I noticed is you have mixed up models and viewmodels (for example IntermediaryViewModel has Branch model instead of BranchViewModel) and in Create POST action, you are adding viewmodel to context models (entities).

All of your code is good if you have taken care of model-viewmodel conversion process via some operator or something of that sort. But if that is the case, you don't get the error that you are seeing now which making me to think there is no such conversion going on in your code.

**Updated your code to include Conversion from Model to ViewModel.**

```
public class Intermediary
{
    public int IntermediaryID  { get; set; }
    public string RegisteredName { get; set; }
    public string TradingName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
}

public class Branch
{
    public int BranchID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Generally Model classes should not have any idea on Display related stuff.
    // [DisplayName("Creation Date")]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    // [DisplayName("Created By")]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class IntermediaryViewModel
{
    // I just created common expression so it can be used from Index as well as Details actions.
    // Feel free to remove this common expression and have the code inside controller actions if you prefer that way. 
    /// <summary>
    /// Lambda expression converting Intermediary to IntermediaryViewModel
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly Expression<Func<Intermediary, IntermediaryViewModel>> AsIntermediaryViewModel =
    i => new IntermediaryViewModel{
        // Please add other required properties mapping here. I just showed couple 
        IntermediaryID = i.IntermediaryID,
        RegisteredName = i.RegisteredName,
        BranchID       = i.BranchID,
        // if you want you can populate Branches (by Intermediary) here like this in a single database call as we have mentioned Include in actions
        Branches = i.Branches.AsQueryable().Select(b => new BranchViewModel{ BranchID = b.BranchID}).ToList()
    };

    public int? IntermediaryID { get; set; }

    [Required,StringLength(150),DisplayName("Registered Name")]
    public string RegisteredName { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(150), DisplayName("Registered Name")]
    public string TradingName { get; set; }
    public int Registration { get; set; }
    public int VATNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FSPNumber { get; set; }

    // As now you have separate ViewModel for display purposes, 
    // you can have string version of CreationDate which is (DateTime to string) converted as per your requirement.
    [DisplayName("Creation Date")]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [DisplayName("Created By")]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    // Since you are defining BranchId as non-nullable, you will need to default to some existing BranchId so, your (create) view will show this branch when page is loaded. Otherwise make it nullable int (int ?) so, dropdown would display your message "Select Branch" when BranchId is null
    public int BranchID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BranchViewModel> Branches { get; set; }
}

// since you are using Branches to populate drop down, other audit properties are not required here.
// Does not hurt having them if you want.
public class BranchViewModel
{
    public int BranchID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}




// GET: Intermediaries
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Intermediaries.Include(i => i.Branches).Select(IntermediaryViewModel.AsIntermediaryViewModel).ToListAsync());
}

// GET: Intermediaries/Details/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    // I just renamed the variable to speak what it represents. 
    var intermediaryViewModel = await _context.Intermediaries.Include(i => i.Branches).Select(IntermediaryViewModel.AsIntermediaryViewModel)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.IntermediaryID == id);
    if (intermediaryViewModel == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(intermediaryViewModel);
}

private void PopulateBranchDropDownList(object selectedBranch = null)
{
    ViewBag.BranchList = from d in _context.Branch
                        orderby d.Name
                        select new BranchViewModel
                        {
                            BranchID = d.BranchID,
                            Name = d.Name
                        }.ToList();

    ViewBag.BranchID = selectedBranch;  //Set to some predefined BranchID selection, so when page is loaded, dropdown will be defaulted to this value.
}
```

Please use the same for other controller actions. No need to change anything in the views as they are already taking ViewModels except that Branch dropdown.

Please notice I have replaced DepartmentID with BranchID

```
@{
    var Branchist = new SelectList(ViewBag.LocList, "Id", "Text");
    int? BranchID = ViewBag.BranchID ?? (int ?)null; // please test this line.
}

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="BranchID">Branch</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList(@BranchID, @Branchist , "Select Branch", new {@class="form-group"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BranchID)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried to make the changes as suggested, however your ModelsToViewModelsConversion procedure says that the async namespace could not be found. Also I am not sure what how to write the conversion code inside the procedure.

Comment: @JasonEbersey ModelsToViewModelsConversion is the user-defined custom function to handle the conversion that you need to create something similar to your custom function user-defined PopulateBranchDropDownList. Since you have not defined that function its giving you that error. Nevertheless the main issue with your code is you mixed up viewmodels and models. Please fix that

Comment: Can you please assist me with the conversion?  I don't know how to convert my model to viewmodel

Comment: @JasonEbersey I have updated my post. Some people prefer AutoMapper to avoid mapping property-by-proerty by hand manually (AutoMapper uses reflection for this mapping) but again its just your preference.

Comment: @JasonEbersey Please pay attention to public static readonly Expression<Func<Intermediary, IntermediaryViewModel>> AsIntermediaryViewModel to see the conversion process.

Comment: I get an error on public static readonly Expression<Func<Intermediary: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Systems.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<BizDevHub.ViewModels.BranchViewModel>'> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @JasonEbersey: huh... I updated the expression. Please refer that.

Comment: Unfortunately it still has the same error on the Expressions.

Comment: Could you post the code after your update. Because AsQueryable() should have fixed Branch Model Enumeration.